How to get which command has executed show task pane in Excel Office.js
We have added multiple button to Excel using Manifest file. This adds new custom tab to ribbon.
Currently we are using different URL for each button to show specific task pane (multiple task pane). But in excel hide taskpane API is not working as it needs shareduntime. But sharedruntime works only with single taskpane.
So to convert my current pages to single task pane application, I want to know which command from ribbon executed that taskpane.
Is there anyway to do the same?
Thanks in advance.
